# "I decided the target for our firm IS TO BE TO provide better services."

Tags: syntax

Suppose I wrote the following:

> I decided the target for our firm **is to be to** provide better services.

Would this be correct?

Comment: "...is to be this, to provide better services."

Comment: What @StoneyB says (as usual): it is grammatically okay, but stylistically lacking.

Answer (score 9):

It is grammatically acceptable; but it is gnarly to read.

There is a linguistic rule-of-thumb called *horror aequi* which states that people don't like to hear or read identical constructions too close together. The back-to-back *to* infinitives violate this rule; you would do better to express futurity with *will*:

> I decided the target for our firm will be to provide better services.

In addition, *target* is not a good choice here. In business-speak, a *target* usually means a specific measurable goal to be achieved in a specific period, such as ‘$20M revenue in 2015’ or ‘Top 5 market share by Q3 2018’. ‘To provide better services’ might better be characterized as your firm’s ‘mission’ or perhaps ‘strategy’.

Answer (score 1):

The correct form would be

> I decided the target for our firm is to provide better services.

Drop the 'to be'

Comment: This has different meaning. Your variant means that the target is (and has been) the same, not that is to be so in the future.

Comment: OK, I didn't get this meaning from your question. If you mean a plan for the future, then the usage is correct.

Answer (score 0):

> *I decided the target for our firm is to be to provide better services*.

Two ideas seem to have become conflated here. Compare:

1. *Our firm is to provide better services*.
2. *Our target is to provide better services*.

In [1], is the *modal* (Palmer 1999.164), *semi-modal* (Leech, 2204.104), *modal idiom* (Quirk et al, 1985.135) or quasi Modal (Huddleston & Pullum, 2002,113-4).